# Is there a better UILabel somewhere?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm looking for an UILabel with the following capabilities:

- auto resize
- support for breaklines
- simple rich text formatting (bold,
  italic, hyperlinks?)

I know I can do it myself, but I'd guess there should be already an open-source project for something like this, right?

Comment: Auto resizing can be easily done by doing: `CGSize textSize = [[myString text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];`
        `myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, textSize.width, textSize.height);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using TTStyledLabel/TTStyledTextLabel  from the [Three20](http://three20.info/) library. It provides the desired functionally and would save you the time of writing your own.